# How to stop Spark resolving UDF column in conditional statement

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to perform some conditional branching to avoid calculating unnecessary nodes but I am noticing that if the source column in the condition statement is a UDF then the **otherwise** is resolved regardless:

```
 @pandas_udf("double", PandasUDFType.SCALAR)
 def udf_that_throws_exception(*cols):
   raise Exception('Error')

 @pandas_udf("int", PandasUDFType.SCALAR)
 def simple_mul_udf(*cols):
   result = cols[0]
   for c in cols[1:]:
     result *= c
   return result

 df = spark.range(0,5)

 df = df.withColumn('A', lit(1))
 df = df.withColumn('B', lit(2))

 df = df.withColumn('udf', simple_mul('A','B'))
 df = df.withColumn('sql', expr('A*B'))

 df = df.withColumn('res', when(df.sql < 100, lit(1)).otherwise(udf_that_throws(lit(0))))
```

The above code works as expected, the statement in this case is always true so my UDF that throws an exception is never called.

However, if i change the condition to use **df.udf** instead then all of a sudden the otherwise UDF is called and i get the exception even though the condition result has not changed.

I thought i might be able to obfuscate it by removing the UDF from the condition however the same result occurs regardless:

```
  df = df.withColumn('cond', when(df.udf < 100, lit(1)).otherwise(lit(0)))
  df = df.withColumn('res', when(df.cond == lit(1), lit(1)).otherwise(udf_that_throws_exception(lit(0))))
```

I imagine this has something to do with the way Spark optimizes, which is fine, but am looking for any way to do this without incurring the cost. Any ideas?

**Edit**
Per request for more information. We are writing a processing engine that can accept an arbitrary model and the code generates the graph. Along the way there are junctures where we make decisions based on the state of values at runtime. We make heavy use of pandas UDF. So imagine a situation where we have multiple paths in the graph and, depending on some condition at runtime, we wish to follow one of those paths, leaving all others untouched.

I would like to encode this logic into the graph so there is no point where I have to collect and branch in the code.

The sample code I have provided is for demonstration purposes only. The issue I am facing is that if the column used in the IF statement is a UDF or, it seems, if it is derived from a UDF, then the OTHERWISE condition is always executed even if its never actually used. If the IF/ELSE are cheap operations such as literals I wouldnt mind, but what if the column UDF (perhaps on both sides) results in a large aggregation or some other length process which is actually just thrown away?

Comment: can you explain you problem clearly..What issue you are facing while using df.udf?

Comment: please add the logic for udf also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PySpark the UDFs are computed beforehand and therefore you are getting this sub-optimal bahaviour. You can see it also from the query plan:

```
== Physical Plan ==
*(2) Project [id#753L, 1 AS A#755, 2 AS B#758, pythonUDF1#776 AS udf#763, CASE WHEN (pythonUDF1#776 < 100) THEN 1.0 ELSE pythonUDF2#777 END AS res#769]
+- ArrowEvalPython [simple_mul_udf(1, 2), simple_mul_udf(1, 2), udf_that_throws_exception(0)], [id#753L, pythonUDF0#775, pythonUDF1#776, pythonUDF2#777]
   +- *(1) Range (0, 5, step=1, splits=8)
```

The `ArrowEvalPython` operator is responsible for computing the UDFs and after that the condition will be evaluated in the `Project` operator.

The reason why you get different behaviour when you call `df.sql` in your condition (the optimal behaviour) is that this is a special case in which the value in the this column is constant (both columns `A` and `B` are constant) and the Spark optimizer can evaluate it beforehand (in the driver during query plan processing, before the execution of the actual job on the cluster) and thus it knows that the `otherwise` branch of the condition will never have to be evaluated. If the value in this `sql` column is dynamic (for example like in the `id` column) the behaviour will be suboptimal again, because Spark does not know in advance that `otherwise` part should never take place.

If you want to avoid this suboptimal behaviour (calling udf in `otherwise` even though it is not needed), one possible solution is that you evaluate this condition inside your udf, for example as follows:

```
@pandas_udf("int", PandasUDFType.SCALAR)
def udf_with_cond(*cols):
    result = cols[0]
    for c in cols[1:]:
        result *= c

    if((result < 100).any()):
        return result
    else:
        raise Exception('Error')

df = df.withColumn('res', udf_with_cond('A', 'B'))
```