# How to fill up null values in Spark Dataframe based on other columns' value?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Given this dataframe:

```
+-----+-----+----+
|num_a|num_b| sum|
+-----+-----+----+
|    1|    1|   2|
|   12|   15|  27|
|   56|   11|null|
|   79|    3|  82|
|  111|  114| 225|
+-----+-----+----+
```

How would you fill up `Null` values in sum column if the value can be gathered from other columns? In this example 56+11 would be the value.

I've tried `df.fillna` with an udf, but that doesn't seems to work, as it was just getting the column name not the actual value. I would want to compute the value just for the rows with missing values, so creating a new column would not be a viable option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your requirement is UDF, then it can be done as:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import LongType

df = spark.createDataFrame(
   [(1, 2, 3),
   (12, 15, 27),
   (56, 11, None),
   (79, 3, 82)],
   ["num_a", "num_b", "sum"]
)

F.udf(returnType=LongType)
def fill_with_sum(num_a, num_b, sum): 
  return sum if sum is None else (num_a + num_b)

df = df.withColumn("sum", fill_with_sum(F.col("num_a"), F.col("num_b"), F.col("sum")))

[Out]:
+-----+-----+---+
|num_a|num_b|sum|
+-----+-----+---+
|    1|    2|  3|
|   12|   15| 27|
|   56|   11| 67|
|   79|    3| 82|
+-----+-----+---+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use coalesce function. Check this sample code

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

df = spark.createDataFrame(
   [(1, 2, 3),
   (12, 15, 27),
   (56, 11, None),
   (79, 3, 82)],
   ["num_a", "num_b", "sum"]
)

df.withColumn("sum", f.coalesce(f.col("sum"), f.col("num_a") + f.col("num_b"))).show()
```

Output is:

```
+-----+-----+---+
|num_a|num_b|sum|
+-----+-----+---+
|    1|    2|  3|
|   12|   15| 27|
|   56|   11| 67|
|   79|    3| 82|
+-----+-----+---+
```

Comment: Thanks. Would that work with an UDF? Because I need to perform some other calculations too, including some REST API calls.

Comment: You can but its tricky and i dont have much expirience with udf in when/otherwise so i cant advise you how to exactly do it in your case. You can check this answer, i think that it provides a lot of details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58447674/how-to-stop-spark-resolving-udf-column-in-conditional-statement